# Azure CDN for Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure CDN for Azure Website     I have an Azure Website and I would like to serve some of it via an Azure CDN. Apparently, this used to be possible by using a /cdn folder in an Azure Hosted Service however, you cannot create these any more.

If I try and create a Cloud Service (which replaced the Hosted Service), I just end up creating an Azure Web Site and you cannot connect a CDN to it.

So, my question is: How can I connect an Azure CDN to an Azure website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[App Service](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=529714) can be integrated with [Azure CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/cdn/), adding to the global scaling capabilities inherent in [App Service Web Apps](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=529714) by serving your web app content globally from server nodes near your customers (an updated list of all current node locations can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg680302.aspx)). In scenarios like serving static images, this integration can dramatically increase the performance of your Azure App Service Web Apps and significantly improves your web app's user experience worldwide.

Integrating Web Apps with Azure CDN gives you the following advantages:

- Integrate content deployment (images, scripts, and stylesheets) as part of your web app's [continuous deployment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) process
- Easily upgrade the NuGet packages in your web app in Azure App Service, such as jQuery or Bootstrap versions
- Manage your Web application and your CDN-served content from the same Visual Studio interface
- Integrate ASP.NET bundling and minification with Azure CDN

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a Azure Webapp, create a azure CDN profile in azure new portal (and select the pricing tier between Akamai and Verizon which azure CDN currently offers).

Next create a CDN endpoint, and point this endpoint to azure webapp (while creating the CDN endpoint). The objects to be cached can be controlled by configuring in the CDN management portal (which is link with azure new portal). Also verizon CDN has even the flexibility of specifying the patterns to cache, and it gives a nice overview of what is cached and what is not based on country information as well